# Counting the values in function with python

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have the following function

```
def sum_NE(data, i, col='VALUES'):
   return data.iloc[get_NE(i, len(data))][col].sum()
```

This works great. But I'd like to do one more thing. Column `VALUES` includes zeros and values bigger than zero. How do I count all the values bigger than zero, that are used when evaluating `sum()`?
Function `get_NE` returns a list. I tried the code below, but it doesn't work.

```
def sum_NE(data, i, col='VALUES'):
    return data.iloc[get_NE(i, len(data))][col].count()
```

Function `get_NE` is a function that returns a list. E.g. [5, 6, 8, 12]. These values are  rows in `data` dataframe and with `[col]` reference i'm looking at certain values in `VALUES` column. Those values are at first aggregated. Now i want to find out how many of those values are aggregated.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and your expected output? It's not clear what you are trying to calculate. Also what is `get_NE()`?

Comment: What about `len(data.iloc[get_NE(i, len(data))][col])`?

Comment: @angelwally len() returns the same results as my proposition with count(). It doesn't exclude 0 values

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
def sum_NE(data, i, col='VALUES'):
    return sum(1 for i in data.iloc[get_NE(i, len(data))][col] if float(i) > 0)
```